# UPDATE does not work in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a form in PHP in order to select the value I want to change and to the select the value that will be the new one. The SQL query runs with success but the update does not happen.

the form part of **index.php**:

```
<form action="filmpontozas.php" method="POST">
    <select name="cim">
    <option disabled selected value> -- Válassz egy filmet! -- </option>

    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT cim FROM film";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Hibás utasítás: '.mysqli_error($conn));


    while ( ($current_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))!= null) {
        $cim = $current_row["cim"];
        echo '<option value="'.$cim.'">'.$cim.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><select name="filmAZ">';
    echo '<option disabled selected value> -- Válassz egy pontszámot! -- </option>';


    $sql = "SELECT filmAZ, pontszam FROM film";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Hibás utasítás: '.mysqli_error($conn));


    while ( ($current_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))!= null) {


        echo '<option value="'.$current_row["filmAZ"].'">'.$current_row["pontszam"].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Értékel!">

</form>
```

**filmpontozas.php**

```
<?php

$cim = $_POST["cim"];
$filmAZ = $_POST["filmAZ"];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'magyarimdb') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$sql = 'UPDATE film SET filmAZ = '.$filmAZ." WHERE cim = '".$cim."'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

header("Location: koszonjuk.html");
?>
```

Comment: Wrap the quotes around `$filmAZ` ....

Comment: remove the `Location:` redirect and show us the printed error. I suspect it because you have not wrapped fileAZ value with single quote.

Comment: There is no error, I removed it and the **filmpontozas.php** showed up, which is right now an empty, white page

Comment: Really, you should be using parameterized queries to get around SQL injection attacks. This question should never have been posted as there's plenty of duplicate questions similar to this all over the place. Research first before jumping the gun in posting to SO as a shortcut for your laziness.

Answer (score 2):

Update your MySQLi Query like below:

```
$query = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE film SET filmAZ=? WHERE cim=?");
// Check whether the prepare() succeeded
if ($query === false) {
    trigger_error($this->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    return;
}
$query->bind_param('si', $filmAZ, $cim);
$status = $query->execute();
// Check whether the execute() succeeded
if ($status === false) {
    trigger_error($query->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Would be better to use `$query` instead of a short 3 character variable name like `$qry`. Meaningful variables make code so much easier to read. And perhaps also a try catch around the query execute statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the newer version, now I try to update an another field.

```
 <?php 

        if(ISSET($_POST["cim"]) && ISSET($_POST["filmstudioAZ"])){

            $cim = $_POST["cim"];
            $filmstudioAZ = $_POST["filmstudioAZ"];

            $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

            mysqli_select_db($conn, 'magyarimdb') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

            $sql = 'UPDATE film SET filmstudioAZ = '.$filmstudioAZ." WHERE cim = '".$cim."'";

            echo $sql;
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }

        //header("Location: koszonjuk.html");
    ?>
```

I really dont know what the problem. I echo the query and when I see the result it prints this:

UPDATE film SET filmstudioAZ = 1 WHERE cim = 'Honfoglalás'

For some reason the **mysqli_query()** does not runs this sql query because there is no update in my database when I run my program. But when I copy into **phpmyadmin** and I run it as sql query, the update happens. I really don't know what to say.

Comment: Please do not post updates to your question as answers, edit your original question instead. If you feel that the original version of your question needs to be preserved for clarity, just append your edit below the original version.